# PyQt5 pausing a while loop, operating a file writing function and resume it again

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a simple GUI that has two main buttons. One of the buttons is running a scrapping function in a while loop and append some items into a list. The other button I want it to write a file from the list generated by the loop function without stopping the loop. It is more like posing the for-loop while the script is creating a text file.  I am struggling figure out a way to make it work.

The following error shows in `self.save.clicked.connect(self.writer(self.links))`

> TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Here is what I have done:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
import time
from sys import exit
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from sys import exit

class Ui_window(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.links = []

    def writer(self, links):
        with open('{}_links.txt'.format(len(links)), "w+", newline = '') as file:
            file.write("\n".join(links))

        def loop(self):
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING) 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

    while True
        #Dynamic page with infinite scroll
        browser.get('www.example.com/posts')
        WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="posts"]')))
        for I in range(random.randint(3,12)):
            scroll = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            time.sleep(4)

        page = browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

        posts = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'user_post'})
        for i in items:
            self.links.append(i)
            else:
                pass

    def setupUi(self, window): 
        window.setObjectName("window")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
        self.start.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(383, 23))
        self.start.setStyleSheet("")
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.start)
        #### looping ####
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.loop)
                ##
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(window)
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.save)

        #### pause loop and save ####
        self.save.clicked.connect(self.writer(self.links))
                ##
        self.retranslateUi(window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(window)

    def retranslateUi(self, window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        window.setWindowTitle(_translate("window", "test"))
        self.start.setText(_translate("window", "start"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("window", "pause"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_window()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Change `def writer(links, self):` to `def writer(self, links):`

Comment: thanks for spotting it.

Comment: To those voting to close, please note **that this question is not actually solved**. The answer is likely going to need threading or some other sort of asynchronous solution.

Comment: @frorekable Could you please update your question. I assume that the error message has now gone away, but your program doesn't do what you want. Could you please expand on what the `loop` function is actually doing? Right now it appears that you are repeatedly (`while True`) iterating over a non-existent list (`for i in items`) which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Describing what you want to do in more detail will help in producing a solution.

Comment: @three_pineapples I apologise for my poor exolanation, I was trying to shorten the code so I does not take much spase, but it wasn’t a good idea. 
The error is still showing, though it is a ‘Type error’ now I have updated the code, I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Change `self.save.clicked.connect(self.writer(self.links))` to `self.save.clicked.connect(lambda checked: self.writer(self.links))
`
`

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc, there is no errors now, but the GUI is (Not Responding) after it starts the script. When I click anything a message shows saying python is not responding.

Comment: you have many syntax errors. :D

Comment: @frorekable Blocking tasks are not suitable for a GUI because they block the main loop where the GUI is executed, it is appropriate to implement those tasks in another thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc what do you suggest for achieving such thing? sorry I am total noop in GUIs

Comment: Read about QThread, there are a lot of examples of similar questions in SO